# Pasar Excel creado por PHPExcel a PDF de manera automatica

Tags: php, pdf, phpexcel

Buenas tardes como el titulo lo indica necesito generar un PDF de un archivo .xlsx creado con la lib. PHPExcel aquí les dejo un pequeño código de como genero el .xlsx

```
require_once '../lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';
include '../lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("copia.xls");
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'prueba');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
ob_start();
$objWriter->save("php://output");
```

La consulta seria según este código como genero el PDF sin cambiar la librería o la forma de generarlo ya que son muchos los reportes que se necesitan pasar a PDF.

Comment: Dependiendo de la plataforma del servidor donde se ejecuta PHP (windows, linux, multiplataforma) pueden haber distintas alternativas mas o menos complejas. Puedes especificar ?

Comment: El PHP se ejecuta en Xapmm, windows server 2016

Answer (score 0):

Una opcion es usar la utilidad de LibreOffice llamandola como un comando de sistema:

```
require_once '../lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';
include '../lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("copia.xls");
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'prueba');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
ob_start();
// guardar excel en archivo (temporal, o puede ser una ruta donde guardarlo permanente)
$excelfile=tmpname("excel",".xls");
$objWriter->save($excelfile);
// Convertir xls a PDF 
$pdffile=tmpname("excel",".pdf");
$outdir=sys_get_temp_dir();
shell_exec('C:\ruta\a\libreoffice\program\soffice.exe --headless --convert-to pdf:calc_pdf_Export --outdir '.$outdir.' '.$pdffile);
// si se va a descargar directamente, a la salida estandar
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=export.pdf");
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
readfile($pdffile);
```

Puedes [descargar Libreoffice gratuitamente](https://es.libreoffice.org/descarga/libreoffice/) y tomar nota de la ruta de instalacion para ajustar el script. Tambien puedes ajustar las rutas de escritura para acomodarlo a lo que necesitas.