# Enviar EXCEL por correo PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer, phpspreadsheet

Estoy trabajando con PHP y MYSQL. En mi sistema tengo un formulario para ingreso de solicitudes y en las opciones del formulario puedo adjuntar múltiples PDF que posteriormente son enviados por correo con la librería PHPMAILER. Además de esto, se crea un Excel (PHPSPREADSHEET) con la información ingresada a la solicitud. Este Excel he logrado guardarlo en una carpeta en mi sistema.
Lo que necesito y por ahora no he resuelto, es que el Excel se envíe por correo junto con los otros archivos que adjuntó el usuario. He buscado por varios sitios pero no he logrado hacerlo. Les agradecería que alguien me pueda orientar.

////////////////CREO MI EXCEL Y LO GUARDO EN LA CARPETA LOCAL DE MI SISTEMA ////////////

```
  $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
  $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
  $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Solicitud');
  $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
  $writer->save('./EXCEL/Solicitud 10.xlsx');
```

//////////////ENVIO CORREO CON LOS ADJUNTOS INGRESADOS POR EL USUARIO////////////////////

```
 $archivos = $_FILES['archivos'];
 $nombre_archivos = $archivos['name'];
 $ruta_archivos = $archivos['tmp_name'];

 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
 $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;    // Activar autenticación SMTP
 $mail->Host       = 'XXXXXX';   // SMTP Server
 $mail->Username   = 'alertas@xxxxxx.cl';     // Cuenta SMTP
 $mail->Password   = 'xxxxxxx';    // Password de la cuenta
 $mail->isHTML(true);
 
 $i = 0;
 foreach ($ruta_archivos as $rutas_archivos) 
 {
  $mail->AddAttachment($rutas_archivos,$nombre_archivos[$i]);
  $i++;
 }

 $mail->ClearAllRecipients(); // Elimina direcciones anteriores si se usa iteradamente
 $mail->setFrom('xxxxx@xxxxx.cl', 'Sistema');
 $mail->addAddress('xxxxx@xxxxxx');
 $mail->Subject  = 'Solicitud';

 $Message = '<html><head>'.PHP_EOL;
 $Message .= '</head><body>'. PHP_EOL;
 $Message .= '<p>Le informamos que fue ingresada Solicitud,
              para <B>'.$nombre.'</B>, según detalles en planilla adjunta </p>'. PHP_EOL;
 $Message .= '</body></html>'. PHP_EOL;

 $mail->Body = $Message;
 $mail->send();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné, les dejo el código, en el caso de que alguien lo necesite.

```
  $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
  $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
  $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Solicitud');
  $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
  $writer->save('./EXCEL/Solicitud.xlsx');


  $archivos = $_FILES['archivos'];
  $nombre_archivos = $archivos['name'];
  $ruta_archivos = $archivos['tmp_name'];

  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
  $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;    // Activar autenticación SMTP
  $mail->Host       = 'XXXXXX';   // SMTP Server
  $mail->Username   = 'alertas@xxxxxx.cl';     // Cuenta SMTP
  $mail->Password   = 'xxxxxxx';    // Password de la cuenta
  $mail->isHTML(true);

  // ADJUNTO EXCEL

  $mail->AddAttachment('./EXCEL/Solicitud.xlsx' , 'Solicitud.xlsx'); 


  // ADJUNTO LOS ARCHIVOS INGRESADOS POR EL USUARIO 

  $i = 0;
  foreach ($ruta_archivos as $rutas_archivos) 
  {
   $mail->AddAttachment($rutas_archivos,$nombre_archivos[$i]);
   $i++;
  }

  $mail->ClearAllRecipients(); 
  $mail->setFrom('xxxxx@xxxxx.cl', 'Sistema');
  $mail->addAddress('xxxxx@xxxxxx');
  $mail->Subject  = 'Solicitud';

  $Message = '<html><head>'.PHP_EOL;
  $Message .= '</head><body>'. PHP_EOL;
  $Message .= '<p>Le informamos que fue ingresada Solicitud,
          para <B>'.$nombre.'</B>, según detalles en planilla adjunta </p>'. 
  PHP_EOL;
  $Message .= '</body></html>'. PHP_EOL;

  $mail->Body = $Message;
  $mail->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Chequeaste la generacion del archivo que se haga correctamente? si es asi verifica que este en $nombre_archivos y $ruta archivos antes de cargar el codigo que envia el mail. En caso que quieras adjuntarlo siempre mas alla de lo que venga del formulario que trae los archivos podes agregarlo, para eso lo harias de la siguiente forma.

```
 $archivos = $_FILES['archivos'];
 $nombre_archivos = $archivos['name'];
 $ruta_archivos = $archivos['tmp_name'];

 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
 $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;    // Activar autenticación SMTP
 $mail->Host       = 'XXXXXX';   // SMTP Server
 $mail->Username   = 'alertas@xxxxxx.cl';     // Cuenta SMTP
 $mail->Password   = 'xxxxxxx';    // Password de la cuenta
 $mail->isHTML(true);
 
 //AGREGADO
 $rutas_archivos[] = './EXCEL/Solicitud 10.xlsx';
 $nombre_archivos[] = 'solicitud';


 $i = 0;
 foreach ($ruta_archivos as $rutas_archivos) 
 {
  $mail->AddAttachment($rutas_archivos,$nombre_archivos[$i]);
  $i++;
 }

 $mail->ClearAllRecipients(); // Elimina direcciones anteriores si se usa iteradamente
 $mail->setFrom('xxxxx@xxxxx.cl', 'Sistema');
 $mail->addAddress('xxxxx@xxxxxx');
 $mail->Subject  = 'Solicitud';

 $Message = '<html><head>'.PHP_EOL;
 $Message .= '</head><body>'. PHP_EOL;
 $Message .= '<p>Le informamos que fue ingresada Solicitud,
              para <B>'.$nombre.'</B>, según detalles en planilla adjunta </p>'. PHP_EOL;
 $Message .= '</body></html>'. PHP_EOL;

 $mail->Body = $Message;
 $mail->send();
```

Saludos

Comment: Hola, agregue tu código y realice varias pruebas, pero no logré enviar el Excel por correo..

Answer (score 0):

Has considerado guardar el excel como un pdf?

en este otro posteo se muestra como hacer el paso de excel a pdf!
[Como pasar de Excel a PDF](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/387475/pasar-excel-creado-por-phpexcel-a-pdf-de-manera-automatica)

Comment: Ese enlace parece bastante extraño, la verdad...

Comment: corregí el enlace, gracias

Comment: Es una buena alternativa, lo intentaré gracias.